# How do I set up my home server to go directly to a port other than 80

Tags: tomcat, dynamic-dns

I'm using dyndns, a lynksis wt54g router, and tomcat 7 with spring to set up a web server.  This is my first time to attempt this.  I'm sure this is a very common question, but I don't know enough to find the answer after quite a bit searching.  Dyndns is successfully forwarding to my ip.  The main problem is, the router admin login is coming up when my url is used.  I'm hosting my site on port 8080.  I have port forwarding set up for port 8080 but my request times out when I attempt to use my url like this `www.myurl1234.com:8080`.  I don't want users to have to type the port anyway.  I also tried changing the management port to 82 and hosting on port 80, but I still get the router admin login when I use my url.  Where am I going wrong?  Can I set it up so that `www.myurl1234.com` goes straight to port 8080?

Comment: You can set up a web server on port 80 and from there use HTTP or JavaScript to forward the browser to port 8080 on the same host, but you can't make [`example.com`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) route to `example.com:8080`. Port 80 is the default port for HTTP, so unless you tell the browser to connect to the host at a different port, that's the port it will use.

Comment: You say that you have port 8080 forwarded by your Router...
Is your web server on your machine configured to Listen on the 8080 port?
Are you running these URL queries on a machine connected to that router?
(If so, it will always get the router admin page...)

Answer (score 3):

See your router's manual... Sounds like you have it badly misconfigured if the management page is publicly available.

Comment: Second this, move the routers page from port 80, set a good password on it, and forward port 80 to your internal server.

Comment: @fstx: You don't actually need to change port number for the router web admin page. Because if you disable remote administration, then the router's embedded web server won't bind to the public IP, and you can just forward outside connections to port 80 directly to your server. And other hosts on your LAN would be connecting to your server via its LAN IP.